# Select Template before create Promo

Tags: templates, components

I have multiple promo template in template folder, may i know how to allow user to select a promo template before they create a promo in Experience editor?

This is my Promo Template.
[image]
But in Experience Editor, I seem like cannot select the promo template that i want to use.

[image]

Your help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

In the **Select the Associated Content** dialog box, you can only choose the content item (data source item) that is present under Sitecore\Content\Tenant\Site\Data\Promos (Global datasource path) or the items under the data folder of a page (local datasource). Also, you can only have the datasource items that is created using the default datasource template for promo rendering.

In your case, since you're using a custom datasource template, you may have to follow this solution given by Gatogordo - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/16581/4515

Comment: Hi Paulson Maclean, ok great! Thanks for your help! Appreciate!